# How can i run a module which I've already downloaded?

Tags: python, pip

I was using **discord.py** module and i used **pip freeze** to see my installed modules(or packages idk).Then,I recieved a few error from Pycharm which is *'No module named 'discord'* or *'Unresolved reference 'discord'*.Whenever I try to reload this module,nothing changes,even it says this module is already downloaded.So how can i make this module run?

Comment: Do you get the error when you try to run the code, or is this only an error reported by pycharm?

Comment: @C_Z_Nope,I don't recieve any error.However,my codes don't work properly

Comment: Probably pycharm is not set up with the correct interpreter. Basically pycharm thinks you don't have discord installed because pycharm is using a version of python that is in a different location from where you installed discord. Your code not working properly is unrelated to the error pycharm is complaining about

Comment: @C_Z_Yeah,I just remember,I got an error like what you said.So should i reinstall python and pycharm?

Comment: Yea, install both again and check the Python path in the settings of pycham

Comment: And did u tried running your Python file from cmd or terminal

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
import discord
```

or

```
import discord as d
```

Your possibly referencing the module without actually importing it first

Comment: The problem is with name of module . Your answer will not work in this case

Comment: maybe then try typing `pip install --upgrade discord.py` into your terminal

Answer (score 0):

The error came because you dont have `discord` installed . You have `discord.py`.

So run  :

```
pip install discord
```

Comment: pip install discord

Comment: That didn't help :(